# How to add multiple dynamic themes in a single app

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a question about dynamic theming. I am working on an e-commerce app and in that app, there are two modules, customer and seller. I want to give a color choice to the customer and seller, so they can modify their app as per choice. So here I am setting the dynamic theming, but it will apply to the whole application.

Here is the code which I've referred and used for my app:
https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-theme-switching-bloc-tutorial

Comment: So what is the problem? Don't you manage to switch themes?

Comment: so I've added the switch which change the color of App. but I want to two different switches for the particular user.

Comment: Well can you share some code so that we can see what you achieved so far?

Comment: [https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-theme-switching-bloc-tutorial]. Here is the code i've done same like this